# Jquery: the script stops when ajax request fails with error 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internal-server-error

I have a script that sends ajax request in intervals and ideally it should never cease to work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var delay = 750;
    window.setInterval(endlessJob, delay);
    function endlessJob() {
        //read from endless steam of data
        var data = getData();
        sendAjax(data);
    }

    function sendAjax(data) {
         $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            jsonp: "jsonp",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                q: data
            },
            success: function (res) {
                doSomething();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('ajax error! ' + errorThrown.message + "\n status: " + textStatus);
                //should resume endless job, but the script fails with error(((((((((((
                 window.setInterval(endlessJob, delay);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And then there's the problem: after a number of requests, ussually it's between 1000 and 2000, the request fails with Internal Server Error 500 and the function never resumes. Have already tried try/catch, but with no success(. Basically i need to just ***swallow the error and continue the script***. Can someone assist me please?

Comment: OT: Do you realize you initialize a new interval on every ajax error and thus somewhen will most likely flood your server?

Comment: this is just something i tried to make it work. Also if put endlessJob() is called in there, there's no results. The script fails with error.

Comment: How can the error be ignored, so the script continues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a call to the server every 3/4 of a second over a thousand times.  Eventually you will have calls being made before the previous call has had enough time to complete.  If you want your script to run *for a very long time* i recommend you either extend your delay to say maybe 1500-2000 (1.5-2 seconds depending on your server) or change your code to require a callback.  This way the next call won't be initialized until the previous one has been completed. Here is your code modified with a callback. I did not have time to test it but hopefully it will give you a general idea of how to write it with callbacks.

```
<script>

    function start() {
        var data = getData();

        sendAjax(data, function(callbackText) {
            console.log(callbackText);
            start(); // the previous ajax call is done. we may now start the next one
        });
    }

    function sendAjax(data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            jsonp: "jsonp",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                q: data
            },
            success: function(res) {
                doSomething();
                callback("This call is done. Now moving on to the next one.");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('ajax error! ' + errorThrown.message + "\n status: " + textStatus);
                //should resume endless job, but the script fails with error(((((((((((
                window.setInterval(endlessJob, delay);
            }
        });
    }

    start(); // start the entire process
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Increasing the delay is way to go I suppose, however i was thinking of applying a dynamic delay in there. Something like: at start, it's 750 and gradually increases in every iteration. What are the options here, other than calling window.setInterval when error occurs?

Comment: Or alternatively, can you please come up with a sample of code that uses the callback?

Comment: Sidenote: if you want a dynamic delay, stick with one interval and just skip the ajax call until your delay (stored in a value) was reached. Do NOT use setTimeout to generate a dynamic delay. Most of the current web browsers will eat up your entire free ram and freeze in no time.